# C# Template as base type? if not . how?

Tags: c#, templates, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

```
class Beta : IBeta

class AlphaBeta<TBeta> : TBeta
    where Tbeta : IBeta
```

Tbeta needs to be a type... compiler errr.

how can I get AlphaBeta to be a Beta?

ty

Comment: Your question is a little confusing. Can you re-word it to better explain what you want to happen?

Comment: Depending on your needs, you can do something similar by defining the base type with a generic argument, and defining a recursive constraint: `abstract class Base<T> where T : Base<T>` - See: http://www.somethingorothersoft.com/2010/09/27/crtp-in-c/

Comment: @ Merlyn Morgan-Graham .. awsome. thanks. now im on right track.

Answer (score 3):

You can't do that - generics in .NET aren't the same as templates in C++.

You can give `AlphaBeta` a member variable of type `TBeta`, but you can't make it *derive* from `TBeta`.

If you can give more information about what you're trying to do at a "bigger picture" level, we may be able to give more help. Would implementing `IBeta` be acceptable instead?

Comment: Yes. im trying to avoid implimenting IBeta.. All I would be doing is forwarding everything to Beta.

Comment: @jaybny: That's what you'll have to do, basically.

Comment: so followup question.. C# with no multiple inheritance.. how do you avoid constant copy pasting and decorating?

Comment: so now i have Beta with many events and public methods... now im AlphaBeta who is an IBeta.. but really wants to be a Beta. So i need to use decorator pattern. How to forward all events from this to that? ty

Comment: @jaybny: There are different ways of forwarding events depending on whether you want the source (when the handlers are fired) to be the *real* original object or not.

Comment: do I want the extra function call or not? i guess what im looking for is virtual events. anyways, how can i forward all events to base.. or to an object reference?

Comment: @jaybny: It's not really clear what you mean, I'm afraid. But you should be able to find other Stack Overflow questions about proxying events. Basically you can *either* write add/remove event accessors which call the add/remove accessors on the original object, or you can attach *one* handler to the original object, and then when the event is raised, fire off any handlers attached to the proxy.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest

```
    class AlphaBeta<T> : Beta
        where T : IBeta
```

Because T is the C# generic type handler. You then use constraints to force T to be a class that inherits the IBeta class.